# C# - delete a selected DataGridView row

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have the following code and I would like to delete from a MSSQL database when I select a row from a DataGridView. The point is, the code is working (partially), but after I close the form and I reopen it, the records are still there and DB have not been updated. What would be the problem? Thanks.

```
try
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Doriti sa stergeti autogara?", "Stergere", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.grdAutogari.SelectedRows)
        {
            grdAutogari.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message);}
```

Comment: You're only removing rows from the `DataGridView` - there's nothing in your code that's talking to a database.

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated your code is working partially and germi is also right stating, that you don't write your changes to the database.

One way to do this, is do the following:

Collect all selected rows ids in a collection.
Use that collection in a delete statement to your sql server.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Doriti sa stergeti autogara?", "Stergere", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //parameters cant be System.Int32[]
    var IdsToDelete = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.grdAutogari.SelectedRows)
    {
        grdAutogari.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        //you probably need to use item.ID or the column that holds your 
        //Primary key for your sql statement
        IdsToDelete.Add(item.Index.ToString());
    }
    //assuming you have a DataContext of some sort. 
    //Maybe Entity Framework or Linq-To-Sql
    db.ExecuteCommand("delete from [YOURTABLENAME] where YOURTABLENAME.Id in ({0})", IdsToDelete.ToArray());
}
```

This will delete all selected rows on your server. If you dont have a context, you might need to apply a different technique.

A small demo using the AdventureWorks database can be found here: http://share.linqpad.net/767on5.linq

Answer (score -1):

Try this
[Delete multiple rows from DataGridView based on CheckBox selection in Windows Forms Application using C# and VB.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Delete-multiple-rows-from-DataGridView-based-on-CheckBox-selection-in-Windows-Forms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

in this links it delete selected row .In this check boxes are use for deleting rows.

[Delete Gridview Rows in Asp.net using Checkbox in C#, VB.NET](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/11/delete-gridview-rows-in-aspnet-using-checkbox-csharp-vbnet.html)